# Attach data to HTML elements in server page generation for use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to attach id numbers to my list items such that these numbers can be read in JS. It makes most sense to attach the id when generating the HTML on the server. Is there a good way to do this other than tacking the id to the li's as expando attributes? Or is that the only way other than generating the elements in JS?

To be clear, the expando option would be:

```
<li myid="{{=item.id}}">{{=item.name}}</li>
```

This seems icky to me, but I also don't want to generate a big JS list of the item data which is then used to generate the li's. Is there just no 'proper' option?

Comment: What server language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are custom data-*** attributes for that:

```
<li data-id="{{=item.id}}">{{=item.name}}</li>
```

see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: What browsers now support this?